# Удалить определенный элемент по клику React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, map, key

Как можно удалить определенный элемент через кнопку, созданную в с этим же элементом в методе `map()`?

Я пробовал удалять через ID, но не получалось, ибо ID не отображает действительный порядок элементов. Использую Redux.

Может в методе `map` можно как-то создать переменную, которая будет показывать действительный порядок элементов внутри массива?

Когда я удаляю как на скриншотах, то меняется порядок и ID не соответсвует номеру.

В результате удаляется не то:

```
 // фрагмент компонента 
const Table = (props) => {
return <div className='content' align="center">

    <div className='contentControl'>
        <input value={props.inputname} placeholder={'Name'} ref={nameInput} onChange={OnchangeNameBody}></input>
        <input value={props.inputlastname} placeholder={'LastName'} ref={lastnameInput} onChange={OnchangeLastNameBody}></input>
        <input value={props.inputemail} placeholder={'Email'} ref={emailInput} onChange={OnchangeEmailBody}></input>
        <button onClick={Addtotable}>добавить запись</button>
    </div>

    <div className='table' >
        <table border='2' >
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Name </th><th>LastName</th><th>Email</th><th>id</th></tr>

                {props.tableData.map((i) => <tr key={i.id}>
                
                    <td><input value={i.name} onChange={null}></input></td>
                    <td><input value={i.s_name} onChange={null}></input></td>
                    <td><input value={i.email} onChange={null}></input></td>
                    <td><input value={i.id} onChange={null}></input></td>

                    <td className="ccd" onClick={() => { props.string_delete(i.id) }}> <button className='glo'>удалить</button></td>

                </tr>)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
}

// фрагмент redux 
case STRING_DELETE: {
    state.TableData.splice(action.id-1,1)
    return {
       ...state,
       TableData: [...state.TableData]
                   
    }

 }
```

Comment: добавил компонент целиком

Answer (score 3):

Простой пример с использованием функциональных компонентов и хуков:

```
const Parent = () => {    
    const [state, setState] = useState([ ... ваш список ])
    
    const removeItem = id => {
       setState(prevState => prevState.filter(el => el.id !== id))
    }
    
    return <List items={state} removeItem={removeItem} />
}

const List = ({ items, removeItem }) => {
   return (
       {items.map(item => (
              <li 
                 onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)} 
                 key={item.id}>{item.content}
              </li>
           )
       }
   ) 
}
```

Определяете метод в родителе, далее передаете его в компонент `List`, где он будет добавлен к каждому элементу `<li>` на событие `onClick`.

При клике **изменяете стейт**, удаляя элемент из массива по его ID с помощью метода [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).